# Show a wordpress custom post condtionally using a category term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I created a custom post called `sliders` with a custom taxonomy `slider_cat`. It's for a restaurant and every Wednesday I want a specific post to show only on that day.

Find my code attached:

```php
<?php
$today = date("l");
if ($today == "Wednesday") {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sliders',
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'slider_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'wednesday'
      )
    )
  );
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
  if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
      $query->the_post();
      the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
  }
} else {
  echo '';
}
?>
```

For some reason, it doesn't seem to work so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `l` may be an unwise choice, not all languages call Wednesday `"Wednedsay", e.g. on a french server you might get `"Mercredi"`. Have you tried using `N` instead? That gives you the day of the week as a number 0-7. Also when you say it doesn't work, how is it broken exactly? And how do you tell the difference between when it runs `echo ''` because it isn't Wednesday, and when it is but the loop finds nothing? There's no `else` on the `if( $query->have_posts())` to say nothing was found, and nothing to say that it isn't Wednesday, or even if the sliders are found but have a blank title

Comment: see https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php for the list of formats